# How concentrated is the $t^{th}$ smallest discrete uniform order statistic?

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution, upper-lower-bounds, order-statistics

Let $n,z,t$ be positive integers and let $X_1,\ldots,X_{z\cdot t}$  be i.i.d. random variables that are uniformly distributed over $\{0,\ldots,n\}$.

Let $X_{(t)}$ denote the $t^{th}$ smallest variable among the $X_i$'s.
Then we have that $\mathbb E[X_{(t)}]=n\cdot\frac{ t}{z\cdot t+1}$.

Denoting by $\delta>0$ a target tail probability, I'm looking for bounds on $X_{(t)}$, denoted $\overline{X_{(t)}}$ and $\underline{X_{(t)}}$, such that

$$
\Pr[X_{(t)} > \overline{X_{(t)}}] \le \delta\qquad \mbox{and} \qquad \Pr[X_{(t)} < \underline{X_{(t)}}] \le \delta.
$$

Any thoughts on how to get bounds that are easy to work with?

---

We can assume that $n$ is large (which means its almost as if the variables are distributed over $[0,1]$) is if helps to simplify the question.

---

The motivation for the question comes from the analysis of a fast algorithm to compute a quantile over a large array. Using the [Median of Medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) algorithm, we can deterministically compute any $\phi$'s quantile in linear time. 
However, this may be quite slow in practice.

In contrast, [Quick Select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) chooses a random pivot element, and is not optimal for small or large quantiles.

I want to use sampling to select a "good" pivot that minimizes the expected number of iterations until we get the (say, $\phi=0.999$) quantile.
To that end, I consider using setting $z\approx 1/\phi$ and am wondering what'd be a good value for $t$ to optimize the algorithm.